# Mock is crashing process in umbrella project

Tags: testing, mocking, elixir, meck

**Background**

I have an umbrella project, where I run `mix test` from the root.
In one of the apps, I am mocking the [File](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/File.html) module using the [Mock](https://github.com/jjh42/mock#with_mock---Mocking-a-single-module) library.

**Problem**

The issue here is that when I run `mix test` the process dies, with no error message to show:

```
Manager.Impl.Store.ReaderTest [test/unit/store/reader_test.exs]
  * test list_syndicates/1 returns the list of all known syndicates [L#496]** (EXIT from #PID<0.98.0>) killed
```

**Code**

The code of the test is as follows:

```
defmodule Manager.Impl.Store.ReaderTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  alias Manager.Impl.Store.Reader

  import Mock

  setup do
    %{
      file_io: File,
      paths: [syndicates: ["syndicates.json"]]
    }
  end

  describe "lists syndicates" do
    test_with_mock "returns the list of all known syndicates", %{paths: paths} = deps, File, [],
      read: fn _filename -> {:ok, "[\"utc\"]"} end do
      # Act
      actual = Reader.list_syndicates(deps)

      expected = {:ok, [%Syndicate{name: "UTC", id: :utc, catalog: []}]}

      expected_path = Path.join(paths[:syndicates])

      # Assert
      assert actual == expected
      assert_called(File.read(expected_path))
    end
  end
end
```

In comparison, the follow test (which does not use mock) works just fine:

```
defmodule Manager.Impl.Store.ReaderTest do
  @moduledoc false

  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  alias Manager.Impl.Store.Reader

  import Mock

  setup do
    %{
      paths: [syndicates: ["syndicates.json"]]
    }
  end

  describe "list_syndicates/1" do
    defmodule FileMockListSyndicates do
      @moduledoc false

      def read(path) do
        assert path == "syndicates.json"
        {:ok, "[\"utc\"]"}
      end
    end

    setup do
      %{
        file_io: Manager.Impl.Store.ReaderTest.FileMockListSyndicates
      }
    end

    test "returns the list of all known syndicates",
         %{paths: paths} = deps do
      # Act
      actual = FileSystem.list_syndicates(deps)
      expected = {:ok, [%Syndicate{name: "UTC", id: :utc, catalog: []}]}

      # Assert
      assert actual == expected
    end
  end
end
```

To me this is rather surprising. One alternative crashes the process with no error message, while the other makes everything work.

To me, this indicates one of three problems:

1. A problem with the library Mock
2. A problem with my setup of the library
3. A problem with the test that causes the process to crash

I believe the second and third options to be the most probable, but without any information about the error, I can't be sure. The process simply dies.

**Question**

Why is my process dying, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `test` macro accepting 5 arguments...  The name of the test is the first argument and the context is the second... and technically, the body of the test is the 3rd I believe. https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html#test/3
I'm not following how your failing test is supposed to receive "normal" data.

Comment: I am not using the `test` macro on the failing test, I am using `test_with_mock` from the mock library/

Comment: sorry, I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Mock` depends on `:meck`, which does swap out the complete module
> within the runtime – as in make the VM unload the existing module and
> load the module with the mock code. (...) The best improvement to get
> would be better errors or disclaimers.

Source: https://elixirforum.com/t/mock-is-crashing-process-in-umbella-project/61017/4?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

At the time of this writing, I have tested all major mocking libraries (Mock, [Mox](https://hexdocs.pm/mox/Mox.html) and [Mimic](https://hexdocs.pm/mimic/readme.html)).
Both Mock and Mimic rely on `:meck` underneath. Rather surprisingly, I get the exact same issue with Mimic as I got with Mock, i.e., the process crashes without warning.

This leaves me to the only logical conclusion, which is that the problem I am facing is related to the underlying system that servers as a base for both libraries: `:meck`. This issue does not happen using Mox.

I have therefore decided not to use Mock (nor Mimic) for the application and I am instead injecting the dependencies directly into the functions that need them. This last approach is very lightweight and does allow for `async: true` which gives a noticeable speed increase when running `mix test`.

Because I am only using a very small portion of the external system's API (2 - 3 functions) this fits well with my needs. However, If I were to use all functions from said API (let's say 20) this solution would be rather difficult to manage.

I don't expect the affected modules to evolve in such a direction, so for the time being, I am rather happy.

Here is a sample test for those searching for inspiration (using `File` as an example):

```
setup do
  %{
    paths: [products: ["products.json"]]
  }
end

test "returns list of available products from given syndicate", %{paths: paths} = deps do
  read_fn = fn filename ->
    assert filename == Path.join(paths[:products])

    {:ok, "[{\"name\": \"utc\"}]"}
  end

  deps = Map.put(deps, :io, %{read: read_fn})
  syndicate = Syndicate.new(name: "UTC", id: :utc)

  assert FileSystem.list_products(syndicate, deps) ==
           {:ok, [Product.new(%{"name" => "Bananas"})]}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you mock a module this way, only calls to `File.read/1` are allowed. If anywhere your code calls another function from `File` module, it will fail. To change this behaviour you can use [:passthrough](https://github.com/jjh42/mock?tab=readme-ov-file#passthrough---partial-mocking-of-a-module) option.

Also, for this reason mocking standard library functions is not a very good idea, because you never know where they are called. You can wrap `File.read/1` call in another function, and mock this function instead.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm which functions are being invoked from FIle?
I would expect an error message saying "You are invoking this function and you should not", but instead the process simply crashes silently.

Comment: I have tested this, and it still did not fix the issue.